# How to save a previously drawn image and load it back when previous or next buttons are pressed for a drawing app based on opengl code

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, opengl-es, drawing

I have successfully implemented a drawing app using the GLPaint demo app which makes use of OpenGL. Now my problem is i do not have a way how to implement the previous/next functionality in which the strokes of the previous/next images are shown and i can continue my drawing from where i left earlier.

Any help in guiding me to the right direction is appreciated.

Please find the code as shown below

```
-(void)showImagePrevious{
NSMutableString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",self.imageCounter+1];
fileName  = (NSMutableString *)[fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", fileName]];


// Write image to PNG
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self createImageFromGLView:self], 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
NSLog(@"%d",self.imageCounter);
[imgBackground1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",self.imageCounter]]];
[self erase];
NSString  *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",self.imageCounter]]];

NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

imgDrawnImage.image =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];


if (imgDrawnImage.image == nil)
    NSLog(@"Do real error checking here");

GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(imgDrawnImage.image.CGImage);
GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(imgDrawnImage.image.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
CGContextClearRect( context1, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
CGContextTranslateCTM( context1, 0, height - height );
CGContextDrawImage( context1, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), imgDrawnImage.image.CGImage );


CGContextRelease(context1);

free(imageData);
```

}

```
-(void)showImageNext{
NSMutableString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",self.imageCounter-1];
fileName  = (NSMutableString *)[fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", fileName]];


// Write image to PNG
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self createImageFromGLView:self], 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
NSLog(@"%d",self.imageCounter);
[imgBackground1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",self.imageCounter]]];
[self erase];
NSString  *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",self.imageCounter]]];

NSLog(@"%@",filePath);

NSData *texData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

imgDrawnImage.image =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:texData];

if (imgDrawnImage.image == nil)
    NSLog(@"Do real error checking here");

GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(imgDrawnImage.image.CGImage);
GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(imgDrawnImage.image.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
CGContextClearRect( context1, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
CGContextTranslateCTM( context1, 0, height - height );
CGContextDrawImage( context1, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), imgDrawnImage.image.CGImage );

//glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

CGContextRelease(context1);

free(imageData);
}
```

This method is used to create an UIImage to be saved in the documents directory and i pass self(MyCanvasView) as an argument

```
-(UIImage *)createImageFromGLView:(UIView *)glView
{
int width = glView.frame.size.height;
int height = glView.frame.size.width;

NSInteger myDataLength = width * height * 4;
// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
// gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
// there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width * 4; x++)
    {
        buffer2[((height - 1) - y) * width * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * width + x];
    }
}
// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);
// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

// then make the uiimage from that
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
return myImage;
}
```

Best,

Aditya

Comment: you can take a snapshot of the images drawn before transiting to and fro. For open GL you have to take the image of background and the image of the strokes created by Open GL and merge both to create a single image and save it temporarily.

Comment: Hi Sahron, I tried to do in that way but it does not work for multiple iterations,Only the strokes of the last operation on a drawing are shown, the operations prior to those are over written.So if i draw some strokes goto next drawing and come back to the same drawing and do not perform any operations on that drawing,then when i come back again to it only blank image is stored, but rather it should have stored the 1st operation strokes.

Comment: try to capture screen recording when user starting the draw an image.

Comment: I would think you could store the individual strokes in an array, and the previous and next functions would be essentially moving to an index in the array, clearing the image, and drawing all of the strokes up to that index.

Comment: this isn't really a question... it's way to broad.

Comment: What I did in an ancient paint app that I wrote with different toolset and language but similar concept is capture the canvas as a two dimentional array of pixel with each pixel being represented as an rgb combination. The resulting format was too large so I added a simple run length encoding by getting a pixel and then keeping a count of how many times is it repeated consecutively(eg. aa3333, aa3333, aa3333,aa3344 would become aa3333[3], aa3344). This simple optimization worked wonders since it was simple paint app and resulting images has a lot to be saved. Of course this is very basic.

Comment: Just to add to my last comment. I would then easily save this data to a file and load back from a file and simply render it back from the array of pixels to canvas.

Comment: it works for simulator have u checked it in device ? it shows black image